# Node.js mongoose and async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

js mongoose and async. I need help in determining whether the task is complete so that I can render a html page. The mongoose query and async get the task done. I have tested the code and the database updated correctly as I wanted. However, I am not sure on where to render a page because I dont know when the code will finished the task. I hope someone can provide me with an answer! Thank you

```
router.get('/initialize', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.passport.user.accountType == "Admin" ||
        req.session.passport.user.accountType == "Manager") {
        var date = new Date();
        var requestDate = null;
        if (date.getMonth() + 1 < 10) {
            requestDate = new Date(date.getFullYear() + '-0' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
        } else {
            requestDate = new Date(date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
        }

        var i = 0;
        Relationship.find({manager : { $ne: null }}, function (err, manageRelationshipObject) {
            async.each(manageRelationshipObject, function (relationshipData, callback) {
                Relationship.find({username : relationshipData.username, customerID : { $ne: null }}, function (err, customRelationshipObject) {
                    async.each(customRelationshipObject, function (data, callback) {
                        var managerObject = relationshipData.manager;
                        var workerObject = data.username;
                        var customerObject = data.customerID;
                        i++;
                        Entry.findOneAndUpdate({
                            recordDate: requestDate,
                            customerID: customerObject,
                            workerID: workerObject,
                            managerID: managerObject
                        }, {
                            recordDate: requestDate,
                            customerID: customerObject,
                            workerID: workerObject,
                            managerID: managerObject
                        }, {upsert: true}, function (err, object) {
                            if (err) {
                                return res.send(err);
                            }

                        });


                    });

                });
            });
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`async.each` takes 3 parameters.

- The 1st is the array (`manageRelationshipObject`) √
- The 2nd is the iterator function you want to apply on that array (`Relationship.find`) √
- The 3rd is final callback function, after everything is finished. () x

It looks like you just need to add a 3rd parameter and you're set.

Heres more detailed documentation: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Shall you update exact answer for above example it will be helpful to others also.